# Reshape data.frame from long to wide on time series

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set of 13 stations with more than 20 thousands daily (around 50 years) observations. Each station is placed in single column along with year, month and date on left side as below!
Columns are as (year, month, data, name of the stations (a,b,c,d......m).

```html
Year Month Date a b c d e f g h i j k l m
1961 1 1 0.2 0 0   0.01 0 0 0 0  0  0.04
1961 1 2 0.05 0 0   0 0 0 9.398 1.27  5.842  0.01
1961 1 3 0 0 0   0 0 0 1.27 0  0.01  
1961 1 4 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0  0  0
1961 1 5 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0  0  0
1961 1 6 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0  0  0
1961 1 7 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0  0  0
1961 1 8 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0  0  0
```

And I have to reorder in this dimension by keeping one month in a row and years as column and columns are showing as Year, month, days of month(1,2,3,4,5,........30 or 31 as per month). It should be execute for each station explicitly.

```html
Year Month 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
1960 1 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
1960 1 22 11 0 0 0.3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

For this purpose, I tried `aggregate()` but could not figure it out. Thanks in advance for any sort of help.

Comment: Your input has 13 values for each Year, Month, Date combination (labelled `a` to `m`). Your output doesn't appear to have those values translated, and yet it has 18 columns per Year, Month combination. Could you please explain what's going on? It doesn't seem to be a simple reshaping of the data, so what is it?

Comment: Edited my question @rosscova

Comment: Your data still doesn't make much sense to me. From your description though, you might want to look at `cast` in the `reshape2` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reshape data from long to wide.
I solved it in this way, make subset of each column with year, month and date then execute this code for each.

```
library(reshape) 
reshape(object, idvar =c("Year","Month"), timevar ="Date", direction = "wide")
```