# Reshape long to wide time-series data (Unequal number of time-series within each day)

Tags: r, time-series, reshape

My question is a continuation of the previous questions: [Reshape data.frame from long to wide on time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418665/reshape-data-frame-from-long-to-wide-on-time-series)

But with variations. It is 1) when numbers of hours within each day are unequal (minor) 2) when the start hour of the date varies(major)

For example, let's create a data frame with 1) dates, 2)hours, 3)some measurement -- m. Here I use reshape() to transform the long format to wide format, as suggested by the previous post. But you see the output (dt2), instead of creating the start from "m.1" (or "m.2" that's from our data set), it starts from "m.3". The first-row of the dt dataset.

```
dt <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(character()),
                 File=character(), 
                 User=character(), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

date<-as.Date(c("2018-10-1","2018-10-2","2018-10-4"))
date2<-c(rep(date[1],11),rep(date[2],14),rep(date[3],16))
hour<-c(c(3:13),c(2:15),c(4:19))
m<-rnorm(41)
dt<-data.frame(date2,hour, m)

head(dt)
       date2 hour          m
1 2018-10-01    3 -0.9259174
2 2018-10-01    4  0.4172615
3 2018-10-01    5  0.3981876
4 2018-10-01    6 -0.1894735
5 2018-10-01    7  0.7387315
6 2018-10-01    8  1.2337722

If I use the 
library(reshape) 
dt2<-reshape(dt, idvar =c("date2"), timevar ="hour", direction = "wide")
dt2
        date2        m.3        m.4       m.5        m.6        m.7         m.8        m.9         m.10       m.11      m.12       m.13
1  2018-10-01 -0.9259174  0.4172615 0.3981876 -0.1894735  0.7387315  1.23377223 -0.3740326 -0.007818602 -1.7822049 -1.304608 -1.2114172
12 2018-10-02  0.4961225 -0.6928343 0.5495917  1.9807136 -2.6065999 -1.78083806  1.3777553 -0.543557423 -0.6153750  1.223758 -1.0254392
26 2018-10-04         NA  0.6442237 0.5019143  0.5550032 -1.5300680 -0.08084971  0.5487069  0.618540806  0.3787519  0.219644  0.6488434
        m.2       m.14       m.15      m.16      m.17     m.18      m.19
1        NA         NA         NA        NA        NA       NA        NA
12 -1.54329  0.1743518 -2.3307605        NA        NA       NA        NA
26       NA -1.3063877 -0.6920828 -0.194381 -1.144777 1.585792 -1.320353
```

One solution I have is to padding the missing values first. But it takes a long time -- imagining thousands of days.

```
dt_full <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(character()),
                 File=character(), 
                 User=character(), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
 udate<-unique(dt$date2)
 ludate<-length(udate)
for(j in 1:ludate){
    dt_sub<-subset(dt,date2==udate[j])

    full_minute<-data.frame(2:19,udate[j])
    colnames(full_minute)<-c("hour","date2")

    dt_sub_full <-full_join(dt_sub,full_minute,by=c("hour"="hour","date2"="date2"))
    o<-order(dt_sub_full["hour"])
    dt_sub_full <-dt_sub_full[o,]
    dt_full <-rbind(dt_sub_full,dt_full)
 }

dt_full2<-reshape(dt_full, idvar =c("date2"), timevar ="hour", direction = "wide")
    dt_full2
         date2      m.2        m.3        m.4       m.5        m.6        m.7         m.8        m.9         m.10       m.11      m.12
17  2018-10-04       NA         NA  0.6442237 0.5019143  0.5550032 -1.5300680 -0.08084971  0.5487069  0.618540806  0.3787519  0.219644
110 2018-10-02 -1.54329  0.4961225 -0.6928343 0.5495917  1.9807136 -2.6065999 -1.78083806  1.3777553 -0.543557423 -0.6153750  1.223758
121 2018-10-01       NA -0.9259174  0.4172615 0.3981876 -0.1894735  0.7387315  1.23377223 -0.3740326 -0.007818602 -1.7822049 -1.304608
          m.13       m.14       m.15      m.16      m.17     m.18      m.19
17   0.6488434 -1.3063877 -0.6920828 -0.194381 -1.144777 1.585792 -1.320353
110 -1.0254392  0.1743518 -2.3307605        NA        NA       NA        NA
121 -1.2114172         NA         NA        NA        NA       NA        NA
```

My question is could you please help me think about any faster ways to overcome this issue? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: try with `pivot_wider` `dt %>% mutate(hour = str_c('m.', hour)) %>%  group_by(hour) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% pivot_wider(-c(rn, date2), names_from = 'hour', values_from = 'm')`